# how to do updation through an external button for android app(cordova)

Tags: android, cordova

I know that for updating we need to increment the versionCode and versionName in androidManifest file and then playstore will find if there is any mismatch in these value then it'll notify the user that update is available.
But I want a button for update which will check and notify accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an application on the Market, then on app start-up, fire an Intent to open up the Market app hopefully which will cause it to check for updates.

Otherwise implementing and update checker is fairly easy. Here is my code (roughly) for it:

```
String response = SendNetworkUpdateAppRequest(); // Your code to do the network request
                                             // should send the current version
                                             // to server
if(response.equals("YES")) // Start Intent to download the app user has to manually install it by clicking on the notification
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL TO LATEST APK")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can host a service on a server which returns the current version of the application which is out there on the market. According to the value you can decide to intimate the user. If you want to do it programmatically, you would have to write a plugin for your cordova app.